# Ошибка sqlite sqlalchemy NOT NULL constraint failed: users.id

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, sqlite, fastapi

вот таблицы

```
import sqlalchemy
from db.base import metadata
import datetime


users = sqlalchemy.Table(
    "users",
    metadata,
    sqlalchemy.Column("id", sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sqlalchemy.Column("email", sqlalchemy.String, primary_key=True, unique=True),
    sqlalchemy.Column("name", sqlalchemy.String),
    sqlalchemy.Column("hashed_password", sqlalchemy.String),
    sqlalchemy.Column("is_company", sqlalchemy.Boolean),
    sqlalchemy.Column("created_at", sqlalchemy.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow),
    sqlalchemy.Column("updated_at", sqlalchemy.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
)
```

метод для создания записи с бэкенда

```
    async def create(self, u: UserIn) -> User:
    user = User(
        name=u.name,
        email=u.email,
        hashed_password=hash_password(u.password),
        is_company=u.is_company,
        created_at=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
        updated_at=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
    )
    values = {**user.dict()}
    values.pop("id", None)
    query = users.insert().values(**values)
    user.id = await self.database.execute(query)
    return user
```

выводится исключение sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: users.id
нужно чтобы id самопроизвольно прибавлялось, autoincrement в sqlite sqlalchemy не работает, все уже пробовал. В чем проблема, помогите пожалуйста?

Comment: *autoincrement в sqlite sqlalchemy не работает* Да всё работает - если делать правильно и в соответствии с документацией. [SQLite Autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Comment: как это в sqlalchemy сделать? я ставлю autoincrement=True у меня просто напросто программа не запускается

Comment: sqlalchemy.Column("id", sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True) - вот этот столбец нужно

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html - читать внимательно.

Comment: этот вариант тоже пробовал. Вот такая ошибка sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Argument 'sqlite_autoincrement' is not accepted by dialect 'sqlite' on behalf of <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Column'>

Comment: А как оно оказалось в описании поля? в справке автоинкремент - за его пределами. И это правильно, в SQLite автоинкремент - это атрибут таблицы.

Comment: Поставил за пределы, теперь пишет sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: users.id